# Is there a way to test that default TimeZone is never used in a JUnit Test using EasyMock/PowerMock?

Tags: java, junit4, powermock, easymock

I'd like to prove that a piece of code that I've written is not affected by the default Timezone (set either as a JVM property or through the setDefault() method) as part of a unit test.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

---

The reason that this isn't as simple as setting default Timezone within the test before calling the method is that I'm trying to test safety against a race condition. For example, consider the following:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();

assertEquals(calendar.get(Calendar.DATE), calendar2.get(Calendar.DATE));
```

This test should pass, but what happens if the default timezone suddenly changes between the two `getInstance()` calls, from GMT to Singapore, because another piece of code running somewhere changes the default timezone? Then we have a situation where it might fail.

The only way that I can think of to show that it will be unaffected for all possible changes is to somehow assert that the code does not access the default timezone value, wherever it is.

Comment: Perhaps a parameterized test which takes various time zones to invoke TimeZone.setDefault(...), and asserts the same result for all of cases.  Showing some code would help.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for the comment. I edited the question to make it more clear and added a basic code snippet that might illustrate the problem better.

Comment: Still not sure: do you want to make sure that no code changes the default timezone or do you want to make sure your code does not care what the default timezone is?

Comment: The first could be checked with tools like Checkstyle or just searching the source code; but the latter is probably the safer method.
Andrew already suggested how to do that, if you think of race conditions (why should that happen?) you could run multiple threads in your test, but that gets messy :-(

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I want to make sure that my own code doesn't care what the default timezone is. I know that there is other code running that does change the default timezone, so it's a race condition between my code and some other code that I can't change. The reason that I need the unit test is that I'm trying to show that a code change results in a fix, so basically a unit test that fails before the change, but passes after the fix.

Comment: I know that it's quite challenging to test for race conditions, so it's why I was thinking that there would be some sort of alternative approach, where it's like, if the code even tries to reach for this defaultTimezone singleton or JVM property, it will throw an exception and cause the test to fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, I would provoke the race condition. You add an artificial method to your code and use a partial mock or an manual mock to change the timezone.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
changeTimeZone();
Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();

assertEquals(calendar.get(Calendar.DATE), calendar2.get(Calendar.DATE));
```

If the idea is just to know if a `setDefault` is called somewhere during your code execution, you can use PowerMock to mock `setDefault` and fail if it is called. However, I'm not sure PowerMock can mock java.* classes. You might need a ByteBuddy agent.

There is one pitfall left. The default locale can be set using system properties. However, if the property is changed between the two `getInstance()`, it won't matter.

Comment: Hi Henri, thanks for the comment. So this approach works in the sense that it can show that there is a problem, if I've already identified the issue, but it's not as scalable as I'm hoping for. The limitation is that you have to put the changeTimeZone() method in between every line of code to test, and even then, there's no guarantee that you'll catch it (if we're checking for the equality for the date, the date itself may or may not flip).

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to put some sort of listener on the method TimeZone.getDefault() as part of a test, so that the test fails if that method is ever called?  So this would fail if, for example Calendar.getInstance() were called, because getInstance() calls getDefault(). I'm completely open for other solutions, but I'm looking for a very general/strict solution where I can, for example, add it as an annotation/method to many tests to show that the method is never called.

Comment: However, in your real application, if any thread can change the timezone, it won't solve your problem. If everything occurs in the same thread and you just don't know what code is called, then yes. I will update the answer.

Comment: I think Powermock is the correct solution here so I'm going to accept your answer. For various reasons, it seems like Powermock is conflicting with my other testing utilities so I won't be able to use it for my purposes, but that I think it's way to go for everyone else that has this problem.

Comment: Try to upgrade the test dependencies to get the correct mix of dependencies

Comment: Hi Herni, thanks again for all of the help. I think that the issue is that the JPA testing suite is trying to load TimeZone onto the class loader early so it's conflicting with PowerMock, but there are many other tests where I think it could be used. I opened up another question to address this since it's a bit different. If you had a bit of time, I would be very grateful if you could take a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63304840/throw-exception-whenever-package-protected-static-method-is-called-using-powermo